# Is it possible to split the text in my hoover into multiple lines?

Tags: r, text, shiny, format

I have a graph with a hoover. In this I show a list of names. Sometimes this list is too long and I would like my hoover to split the names into several lines.

So the input for my hoover is this:
`all_names = paste(unique(names_x), collapse = ', ')`

And in 'text' I put this variable. How do I adjust this format to insert a max length of the line or something like that?

```
p <- ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=reorder(f_names,n_totaal), y=n,
                                    fill=jaar %>% as.factor(),
                                    text=c(paste0(n,": ",all_names))))+
               geom_bar(stat="identity",
               position=position_stack(reverse = TRUE)) +
               coord_flip()+
               reverse = TRUE,
               zero_axis = "x")+
               scale_y_continuous(breaks= pretty_breaks())
```

To clarify; the hoover is now
'Anna, Lisa, Bert, Otto, Max, Andreas, Kay, Michaella, Joost, Benny, Howard'.
That is very lang and I would like the hoover to break automaticcaly after length X. Then the hoover would be:

'Anna, Lisa, Bert, Otto, Max, Andreas,
Kay, Michaella, Joost, Benny,
Howard'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what is in `dataframe`? You should provide us with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [stringr package](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/index.html) and combining two things:

1. use [stringr::str_wrap](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_wrap.html) to split long text into chunks of desirable length
2. use [stringr::str_replace_all](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html) to replace defualt `\n` with `<br>` tag

So assuming you have column called `long_text` in your `dataframe` which contains long text you may do this:

```r
dataframe$new_text <- str_wrap(string = dataframe$long_text, width = desired_length)
dataframe$new_text <- str_replace_all(string = dataframe$new_text, pattern = "\\n", replacement = "<br>")
```

and pass this new column as one to hover.